# Rare Entropy sources and Hidden Markov

Tags: education

when selecting rare entropy sources for trng and one can see similarities trough an applied hidden markov model, will it be still good entropy?
(structure is the same, even though type of source input is different)

Comment: more discussion on the two sources:

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/rare-entropy-and-hidden-markov.960121/

Comment: to make more clear: comparing two input sources of equal good entropy, mixing them up, does it make better entropy? (no matter if prng,trng)